# c++ graphical programming

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, 3d

I'm new to c++ 3D, so I may just be missing something obvious, but how do I convert from 3D to 2D and (for a given z location) from 2D to 3D?

Comment: what will you be using this for? in order to take advantage of hardware acceleration and deal with the enormous amount of support code for this, you'll need to learn an API.

Comment: That's not a C++ question. It's a geometry and matrix math question, or it's a question about a particular library or API - but there is no standard 3D graphics API in C++. The most likely ones are DirectX and OpenGL, though you may be dealing with some higher-level layer such as Ogre3D.

Answer (score 4):

You map 3D to 2D via [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). You map 2D to 3D by inserting the appropriate value in the Z element of the vector.

Comment: +1 - but you can do projections for 2D to 3D too. You position your 2D image in 3D space, position your result plane in 3D space, and choose the details of your projection from one to the other. Think of a cinema projector, projecting from a 2D film frame to a 2D screen. The result depends on the position and type (point/directional) of the light source, and the projector may not be lined up right - the film frame not parallel with the screen. And while the screen is 2D, it's still in a 3D space.

Comment: Oh - and maybe the screen isn't flat, for a more interesting 2D to 3D projection.

Comment: @Steve: True enough. I hadn't thought of those.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of casting a ray from the screen onto a plane which is parallel to x-y and is at the required z location. You then need to find out where on the plane the ray is colliding.
Here's one example, considering that screen_x and screen_y ranges from [0, 1], where 0 is the left-most or top-most coordinate and 1 is right-most or bottom-most, respectively:

```
Vector3 point_of_contact(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
Matrix4 view_matrix = camera->getViewMatrix();
Matrix4 proj_matrix = camera->getProjectionMatrix();
Matrix4 inv_view_proj_matrix = (proj_matrix * view_matrix).inverse();
float nx = (2.0f * screen_x) - 1.0f;
float ny = 1.0f - (2.0f * screen_y);
Vector3 near_point(nx, ny, -1.0f);
Vector3 mid_point(nx, ny, 0.0f);
// Get ray origin and ray target on near plane in world space
Vector3 ray_origin, ray_target;
ray_origin = inv_view_proj_matrix * near_point;
ray_target = inv_view_proj_matrix * mid_point;

Vector3 ray_direction = ray_target - ray_origin;
ray_direction.normalise();

// Check for collision with the plane
Vector3 plane_normal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
float denominator = plane_normal.dotProduct(ray_direction);
if (fabs(denom) >= std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon())
{
    float num = plane_normal.dotProduct(ray.getOrigin()) + Vector3(0, 0, z_pos);
    float distance = -(num/denom);
    if (distance > 0)
    {
        point_of_contact = ray_origin + (ray_direction * distance);
    }
}
return point_of_contact
```

Disclaimer Notice: This solution was taken from bits and pieces of Ogre3D graphics library.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do a divide by z.  Therefore ...

```
screenX = projectionX / projectionZ;
screenY = projectionY / projectionZ;
```

That does perspective projection based on distance.  Thing is it is often better to use [homgeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) as this simplifies matrix transformation (everything becomes a multiply).  Equally this is what D3D and OpenGL use.  Understanding how to use non-homogeneous coordinates (ie an (x,y,z) coordinate triple) will be very helpful for things like shader optimisations however.

Answer (score -1):

One lame solution:

```
^ y
|
|
|  /z
| /
+/--------->x
```

Angle is the angle between the Ox and Oz axes (

```
#include <cmath>

typedef struct {
  double x,y,z;
} Point3D;

typedef struct {
  double x,y;
} Point2D 

const double angle = M_PI/4; //can be changed

Point2D* projection(Point3D& point) {
  Point2D* p = new Point2D();
  p->x = point.x + point.z * sin(angle);
  p->y = point.y + point.z * cos(angle);
  return p;
}
```

However there are lots of tutorials on this on the net... Have you googled for it?